Custom File Icons Show Up on iOS but not Catalyst
I have a custom file type with an icon for sharing. The icon shows up for iOS, but not on Catalyst. Relevant plist entry sections included. Can’t seem to narrow down the reason for the difference in behavior between iOS and Catalyst.





FYI - you should not both import and export a given file type. You only do one or the other. If it's a file type that your app invented then you export it. If it's file type used by your app, but someone else invented it, then you import it.

@HangarRash thanks for the heads up - where's that from?

The documentation for the UTImportedTypeDeclarations and UTExportedTypeDeclarations keys mentions their use. Plus my own experience with the keys.
